# Laravel: Facades in workbench unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, laravel-4, lang, facade

I have a Laravel code that throws an Exception using `Lang` facade as the message. This is in a workbench. If I try to test this code I get an error like : `Fatal error: Class 'Lang' not found in...`

The program executes without problems if I try it manually. The issue is when I try to unit test it. I've seen that this happens with all facades

I've looked information regarding this but nothings really helps

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Use the fully qualified class names for facades in packages/workbenches. This applies to both tests and production code. `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;`

Comment: This helps pass one level deep in the problem. Now I have: call to member function get() on a non-object `.../Illuminate/Sopport/Facades/Facade.php` on line 208. How do I include the illuminate/support namespace in testcases?